# CGAL example on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: geometry, ubuntu-18.04, computational-geometry, cgal

I installed CGAL via package manager on ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Then as mentioned on https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/usage.html in order to compile an example program. While I issued:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
```

to configure the examples, I am getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:29 (create_single_source_cgal_program):
  Unknown CMake command "create_single_source_cgal_program".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Kindly help; what should I do?

CmakeLists.txt

```
# Created by the script cgal_create_cmake_script
# This is the CMake script for compiling a CGAL application.


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1...3.15)
project( Triangulation_2_Examples )


if(NOT POLICY CMP0070 AND POLICY CMP0053)
  # Only set CMP0053 to OLD with CMake<3.10, otherwise there is a warning.
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0053 OLD)
endif()

if(POLICY CMP0071)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0071 NEW)
endif()

find_package(CGAL COMPONENTS Qt5)

if(CGAL_Qt5_FOUND)
  add_definitions(-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER -DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)
endif()

if ( CGAL_FOUND )

  # create a target per cppfile
  file(GLOB cppfiles RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)
  foreach(cppfile ${cppfiles})
    create_single_source_cgal_program( "${cppfile}" )
  endforeach()

  if(CGAL_Qt5_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(draw_triangulation_2 PUBLIC CGAL::CGAL_Qt5)
  else()
    message(STATUS "NOTICE: The example draw_triangulation_2 requires Qt and will not be compiled.")
  endif()

else()

    message(STATUS "This program requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.")

endif()
```

Comment: Are you using a cmake script from the CGAL examples or one that you wrote? Also make sure that there is a `find_library(CGAL)` and `if (CGAL_FOUND)`.

Comment: Is that the first error issued by CMake? There might one before that would explain the second error.

Comment: @sloriot I am just trying to run CGAL examples right now... I didn't write anything... I have attached CMakeLists.txt file too...please check.

Comment: @Irineau No it's not the first error...it was showing some missing packages but after installing respective packages .. only this error is remaining

Comment: Where did you get the examples? Did you install libcgal-demo, or did you download CGAL-5.0 and look at those examples (which don't match the version of CGAL you installed)?

Comment: @MarcGlisse  I downloaded CGAL-5.0. How to check which version of CGAL is installed in my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like we're supposed to build **all** the CGAL examples  right away during the CGAL installation (using the `cmake` option `-DWITH_examples=ON`). There are many examples and sub-examples, so it takes a long time to build all of them.

However I was able to build these examples **selectively** one by one (see below). I'm not a CGAL developer, so my approach might be not what they wanted - but anyway I hope it'll be useful for the CGAL community. I'm assuming that the CGAL has been installed without examples.

**Step 1**. Create a directory for CGAL examples with any name you want, and enter this directory:

```
mkdir CGAL
cd GGAL
```

**Step 2**. Copy the `examples` directory from the CGAL distribution into this directory, and make sure it's writable:

```
cp -r <CGAL distribution>/examples .
chmod -R u+w examples
```

**Step 3**. Run `cmake` to generate a `Makefile`. In the case you installed the CGAL into some unusual location you'll need the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` option to tell `cmake` about this location:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<CGAL location> examples
```

**Step 4**. Run `make help` to see all the possible examples you can make. You can select all the examples, which visualize something:

```
make help | grep draw
```

**Step 5**. Build one of `Triangulation_2` examples:

```
make draw_triangulation_2
```

**Step 6**. Enter the example directory and run the example:

```
cd examples/Triangulation_2
./draw_triangulation_2&
```

By the way, for some reason the first `draw_triangulation_2` run shows an empty window on my box, but the second run shows the correct picture.